# Align CSS columns side by side

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If I have the following HTML in a 2 column layout, how can I align them next to each other using CSS Grid?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1.25em;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

article {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<article class="content">
  <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
</article>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <h3>{{ page.date | date: '%B %-d, %Y' }}</h3>
  <p>{{ page.tags | array_to_sentence_string }}</p>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem was that you defined a class using grid but then didn't use it in your HTML but that may have just been a typo in your MCVE.

Second problem is that if you want to set widths in [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) you need to either give a width for each column, use a repeat, or a mix of both. You're trying to use two columns but only specified a width for one.

Third problem is that you used `grid-column: 1;` for both elements. According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column):

> The grid-column CSS property is a shorthand property for [`grid-column-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start) and [`grid-column-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end) specifying a grid item's size **and location*** within the grid row by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic) to its grid placement, thereby specifying the inline-start and inline-end edge of its grid area.

<sup>*emphasis added</sup>

By setting them both to 1 you put them both in the same column. In the snippet below I changed the grid template to be 1fr with a repeat of 2 and set the `aside` to be in the second column instead of the first.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 1.25em;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: left;
}

article {
  grid-column: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">

  <article class="content">
    <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ content }}</p>
  </article>

  <aside class="sidebar">
    <h3>{{ page.date | date: '%B %-d, %Y' }}</h3>
    <p>{{ page.tags | array_to_sentence_string }}</p>
  </aside>

</main>
```